# Is it possible to create a form using only FormData and Submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Is it possible to create a form using only FormData and Submit?

I need it to be a normal submit, as the server retries an html page with a lot of information. It can not be ajax.

Thank you very much for your attention.

It would be something like this

```
var form = new formData()
form.append('inputName':123)
form.action('https://dominio.com')
form.method('post')

form.submit()
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want to be able to *submit* something that appears to the server like a form, is that right? No, you can't do it without making a network request somehow, which requires something like `fetch` or an actual form element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate form data using javascript, but it will still require an XMLHttpRequest to be initiated.

Here's a link to Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

The below example uses key/value data strings

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

You could also generate a query string and submit that via GET

```
request.open("GET", "http://foo.com/submitform.php?val1=aaa&val2=bbb");
```

Check out the article, it will give you the info you need.